# Inner class using container class

Tags: apex, debugging

```
    public class containerClass {

        private String checkAccess;
        public void checkAccessFunc(){ 

        }

        public class innerClass{

            public String InnerClassStr;
            public void InnerClassFunc(){ }

            //Inner class accessing outer class
            public containerClass c = new containerClass();
            c.checkAccess = 'Str';

        }

    }
```

**The above piece of code is throwing me an error - Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: '=' at line 15 column 22**

How else is it possible for inner class to access outer class and vice versa ?

Thanks.

Comment: @Ratan - Why for petes sake are you doing this. You just bumped many of  the new questions off of the main page. There is no need to update year old question with trivial tag updates in bulk

Comment: @Eric is it? sorry I thought that need to clean up

Comment: @Ratan - Maybe this is a question for the meta group. But the edits did not improve the question or the answers so bringing them up to theta after being long buried thus bumping new question down or off the page may not be a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can access the outer class variables.

```
public class containerClass {

        private String checkAccess;
        public void checkAccessFunc(){ 

        }

        public class innerClass{

            public String InnerClassStr;

            containerClass outercls;
            public innerClass (containerClass outercls) {
               this.outercls = outercls;
            }

            public void InnerClassFunc(){
                //Inner class accessing outer class
                outercls.checkAccess = 'Str';
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually saying that you can't have an assignment expression that does not follow a declaration on line 15. In other words:

```
public containerClass c = new containerClass();
```

Is a legal statement, because c is being defined in `innerClass`'s scope. However, the next line:

```
c.checkAccess = 's';
```

Isn't valid *here*, only because you can't have a non-declaration assignment at this point in your code. You could, however, have done this:

```
public innerClass() {
    c = new containerClass();
    c.checkAccess = 's';
}
```

Inside a constructor or initializer block, or inside any normal function, you have access to any references of `containerClass` that is inside your instance, as well as all static variables and methods of `containerClass`.